# Microsoft SQL Server : the parameter is incorrect "exception from Hresult:0x80070057

Tags: sql-server, management-studio-express

After installating SQL Beautifier, I get this error when I Open SSMS.

> The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070057 (E_INVALIDRG)) Create Command bar error 2:VSShell

Comment: ***When*** are you getting this error? When you launch SSMS? When you run a query? When (something else) ?!?!?!?

Comment: Then uninstalling it makes the most sense.

Comment: When I Open SSMS.

Comment: Getting the same exception everytime I press backspace